# Broken image but path is correct

Tags: html, wordpress, web

[My file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM7rU.png)

This is a picture of my file directory. When I try to add the image to my index file with the proper path, I keep getting an error telling me the image is not found. The image is there and this doesnt make sense... What could be a possible issue with it besides the path?

Comment: my path is <img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/> ... It should be working :(

Comment: share your code so I check.

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>
 
     <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h2>My name is: Hannah Sporbert</h2>
        </div>
        </div>
        
<div class="col-xs-12">
First Div YAY!
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: _“I keep getting an error telling me the image is not found”_ – and where exactly is it telling you _specifically that_? “Broken image” does not necessarily mean the request was answered with a 404, it can have other reasons (such as corrupted image data) as well.

Comment: try this I think work <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/logo.png" alt="logo"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src="/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
```

instead of

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/>
```

just add "/" before the logo.png like /logo.png